# Capture variable of type json object in postman and get it inside apache camel Java Quarkus

Tags: java, json, apache-camel, quarkus

I am currently working with Apache Camel and Quarkus and as part of a new development, I need to capture a parameter in the header that comes in the form of a json object and I need to obtain it to validate if it contains a value called sub, example:

```
x-token-info --> {"sub": "0F4DDFA38E06232DD40A182C30A97DE54432234"}
```

I need to capture it in camel, but I can't do it, I usually calculate the header parameters as follows:

```
String tokenInfo = exchange.getIn().getHeader("x-token-info").toString();
```

I am trying to obtain the value of the sub field with the following lines to take it to a json object and then to an array, but it gives me the error detailed below:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(tokenInfo);
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<String> list = mapper.readValue(String.valueOf(jsonArray), List.class);
```

Below is a detail of the error:

```
class org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to class org.json.JSONObject (org.json.simple.JSONObject and org.json.JSONObject are in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @223f3642)
```

I have tried other ways to capture the json object, but I have no solution, I must clarify that the x-token-info is a field in which the json object can change the parameters it sends, so it is a standard object or class

Comment: Have you tried with the jsonpath language? https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/languages/jsonpath-language.html

Comment: it seems like you are missing some dependencies in your classpath. Can you try it with io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject instead ? This one is usually included in Quarkus. You can use it like this: `new Jsobject(tokenInfo).getJsonArray("my-array")`

Comment: @JamesNetherton I don't quite understand how to use the JsonPath to capture the value from the header, do you have an example?

Comment: @Serkan add the following extension in the pom https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.vertx/vertx-core/4.5.2 , however, it gives me an error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/vertx/core/net/impl/transport/Transport

Comment: You don’t need to include that dependency. JsonObject should be in your classpath. Can you show your pom.xml ? And in the case JsonObject isn’t on your classpath, then add quarkus-vertx to your classpath.

Comment: An example of using JsonPath to operate on JSON stored in a header: https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/languages/jsonpath-language.html#_using_header_as_input